# Unsupported method: Statement.setCursorName, WAS 8.5.0 ,AIX , Oracle 11

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, aix, websphere-8

I am getting below error during application data fetching.

```
SingleCollect E   java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [MyCompany][Oracle JDBC Driver]Unsupported method: Statement.setCursorName

SoapServicesIm E   Unable to perform operation on method 'getTemplate' of webservice 'AppServices' due to the following reason: A database error has occured[00010040013] Details: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [MyCompany][Oracle JDBC Driver]Unsupported method: Statement.setCursorName.
```

Environment:

AIX 7 , datadirect.jar , Oracle11, WAS 8.5.0

The same datadirect.jar with oracle database is working perfectly on Windows server 2008 + WAS 8.5.5.2.

I seriously dont know what i have missed. I have done the same configuration on both the cases.

Source code where i am getting error: (Error zone - prepStatement.close())

```
finally{
    try
    {
       if (results != null){
                results.close();
       } 
       if (prepStatement != null){
                prepStatement.close();
       }
       if (connect != null){
                connect.close();
    }
        }
```

Any suggestion will really helpful to me.

Updated :

**StackTrace :**

```
FFDC Exception:java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper ProbeId:310 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement@ac8a02e8
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [MyCompany][Oracle JDBC Driver]Unsupported method: Statement.setCursorName
   at com.myproduct.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcr.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.myproduct.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcr.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.myproduct.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcq.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.myproduct.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcq.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.myproduct.jdbc.oraclebase.dddj.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.myproduct.jdbc.oraclebase.dde3.setCursorName(Unknown Source)
   at com.myproduct.jdbcx.oraclebase.dds.setCursorName(Unknown Source)
   at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.doStatementCleanup(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:774)
   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:490)
   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:241)
   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:194)
   at com.myproduct.mdi.services.RecordCollection.executeQuery(RecordCollection.java:432)
   at com.myproduct.mdi.server.impl.AppServicesImpl.getTemplate(AppServicesImpl.java:792)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.invokeTargetOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:101)
   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)
   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:198)
   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
   at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1544)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)

 ==> Performing default dump from     com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DiagnosticModuleForAdapter :Tue Oct 06 12:21:27 IST 2015
 This is a FFDC log generated for the Default Resource Adapter from source:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper
 The exception caught:java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [MyCompany][Oracle JDBC Driver]Unsupported method: Statement.setCursorName
SQL Error Code is 0 SQL State is :HY000
Operating System:AIX 7.1 ppc64
```

Comment: Can you show us like how are you invoking `setCursorName` method

Comment: I am not invoking any thing related to setCursorName. When the debug point reaches prepStatement.close(); it is throwing error with info above. During debugging, I have seen IBM's WSJdbcPreparedStatement as class.

Comment: @Naresh Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Please find the updated stacktrace above.

Comment: One more difference, which i have identififed is, in working copy, i had "JDBC driver specification level 4.0" in log but in nonworking copy. Apart from that , everything is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially thanks for your support and time.

This issue was resolved by upgrading WAS to 8.5.5.2. Now , i didn't get any error. Able to login and do all operations.

Other solution if you dont want to upgrade your WAS is, set builtin property "extendedOptions" to value "throwExceptionForUnsupportedMethods=false" under custom properties of your application datasource. Hope this helps if anyone faces the similar problem.